# PHP sessionに格納されたものをforeach文で出力したい

Tags: php

PHPの初心者です。
ショッピングカートを作る勉強中です。
商品情報をセッションに格納し次のページに送りたく試している最中です。
サイトを参考にしたのですが上手くいきません。
どなたか教えていただけませんか。

商品情報があるページには以下のphpを記述しました。

```
 <?php
   session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['syohinnum'])){
        $syohinnum = $_POST['syohinnum'];
        $syohinname = $_POST['syohinname'];
        $tanka = $_POST['tanka'];


              if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$syohinnum])) {
                  print 'すでにカートに入っています。';
              }else{
                  $_SESSION['cart'][$syohinnum]['syohinnum'] = $syohinnum;
                  $_SESSION['cart'][$syohinnum]['syohinname'] = $syohinname;
                  $_SESSION['cart'][$syohinnum]['tanka'] = $tanka;
            }
    }
?>
```

次のページにforeach文を以下のように記述したのですが、(foreach文以外は省いてあります。)
まったく表示されません。

```
session_start();


foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart) {

  echo $cart['syohinnum'] ;
  echo $cart['syohinname'] ;
  echo $cart['tanka'] ;

}
```

ずっと解決できなくて悩んでいます。
よろしければ回答お願いします。。

Comment: １．PHPのバージョンは？２．`cookie`使えてますか？３．このSESSION内の`cart`は何処かで破棄しますか？４．もし破棄するならその仕組みは今書いてますか？どうやって書いてますか？５．この`session_start()`の前には何か記述がありますか？

Comment: 1.PHPのバージョンは7.1.9です。2.cookieにセッションIDは書き込んであります。3.カートを空にするを作り破棄する予定です。4.まだ書いてありません。5.書いてありますがPHPに関係することではないです。

Comment: エラーは、notile:Undefined index:cartとInvalid argument supplied for foreach()というものが出ています。

Comment: 試しにforeachの直前で$_SESSIONをvar_dumpしてみてください。var_dumpについては→http://php.net/manual/ja/function.var-dump.php

Comment: `session_start()`はドキュメントの先頭に書くべきかと…、あと追記情報は質問を編集して記載してください。